# Naming new data types in Python

Tags: python, naming-conventions, conventions

I went through the PEP 8 naming section and I couldn't find a naming convention for classes that function as a data type. My current project is related to exchange rates so I have classes such as 'rate' and 'currency'. I'm treating these like a numeric class with overloaded operators and unique division and multiplication outcomes, etc.

What I'm wondering is about capitalization. Normally I capitalize class names, but you would never capitalize int, float, real, etc. Should I follow class convention and capitalize the first letter, or should I keep 'rate' and 'currency' in lowercase?

Comment: Personally I would capitalize them. Everyone working in Python knows what an `int` or a `float` is, but a lower case `rate` or `currency` at first glance might look like a variable or function call

Comment: Also check out Python's [typing module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) for reference